# Reload UITableView after HTTP request has been processed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let's say I have two classes: One class represents the database where I perform an HTTP GET request.

```
func getObjects(completion: (([Object]) -> Void)?) {

  guard let url = // ...

  let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
          fatalError("Dispatching main queue failed: \(error)")
        } else if let data = data {
          let decoder = JSONDecoder()

          do {
            let objects = try decoder.decode([Object].self, from: data)
            completion?(object)
          } // ...
    // ...
    }
  task.resume()
}
```

The corresponding result object array is passed to a UIViewController which is a different class. Because I instantiate multiple databases based on different configuration objects, I want to display the results sorted in a sectioned UITableView.

```
func load(then: (([(DatabaseConfig?, [Object])]) -> Void)) {
  var allObjects: [(DatabaseConfig?, [Object])] = [(nil, [])]

  Storage.loadDatabaseConfigs(completion: { configs in
    self.configs = configs
  })

  for config in self.configs {
    var objectSection: (DatabaseConfig?, [Object]) = (nil, [])

    let database = Database.init(config: config)

    objectSection.0 = config
    database.getObjects(completion: { objects in
      objectSection.1.append(objects)
    })
    allObjects.append(allObjectsInSection)
  }

  then(allObjects)
}
```

The load and "formatting" works.

I call the `load(then:)` function in `viewWillAppear()`, where I pass the result to the class array which holds all final entries for the TableView. Then, I try to reload the data.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.load(then: { objects in
      self.allObjects = objects
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

I am aware, that the GET request needs its time, so my question is: **How or where do I reload the UITableView?** I obviously need to be sure, that the GET request has been performed successfully and reload after that. I already tried to envoke `DispatchQueue.main.async` for the reloading, but that didn't work.

Comment: is there any error from the url request?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the problem is that you are making several requests and you wish to reload the table view when all requests have finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you make several requests, you really don't want to call your `then` closure until all requests have finished. You could probably use a `DispatchGroup` for this.

```
func load(then: (([(DatabaseConfig?, [Object])]) -> Void)) {
    var allObjects: [(DatabaseConfig?, [Object])] = [(nil, [])]

    Storage.loadDatabaseConfigs(completion: { configs in
        self.configs = configs

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        for config in self.configs {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            var objectSection: (DatabaseConfig?, [Object]) = (nil, [])

            let database = Database.init(config: config)

            objectSection.0 = config
            database.getObjects(completion: { objects in
                objectSection.1.append(objects)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
            allObjects.append(allObjectsInSection)
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            then(allObjects)
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT: As @Macistador noted, loadDatabaseConfigs is async, so the database calls should be made in the `completion` callback of that function.

Comment: As loadDatabaseConfigs seems to be asynchrone it would be probably better to move everything inside the completion closure

Comment: @Macistador That's true. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you so far. I'm still not sure where to put the `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Apart from that: Are you sure that entering and leaving the Dispatch Group belongs into the for-loop and not outside of it?

Comment: You need matching enter() and leave() calls for each getObjects call, and the leave() needs to be executed when the getObjects call for each config is complete. If you do it outside of the loop there's no point in using a DispatchGroup since it will enter and leave within the same runloop, causing it's notify callback to be executed immediately.

Comment: You shouldn't need to move your call to self.tableView.reloadData(). Keep it where it is.